# Regex replace function not updating DOM in expected manner

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am trying to update my html using regex and javascript. I can capture the group I intend, however nothing on the dom is changing the way I would expect.

I want to discover all currency mentions of AUD, I have a regex that is capturing that. I then need to change how it is displayed.

I used the .replace function, however it does not seem to change anything. It only seems to change it in the console.log.

10AUD

Help us all

```
<p> 20THB</p>

<p> There is 100USD, here</p>

<p>More random sentances that should not be evalued even with 500 numbers in it</p>

<p>Here I can write a bunch like I had 300THB in my pocket and a spare 50AUD note aswell</p>
```

Here is the js portion.

```
regAUD = RegExp(/([0-9]+(AUD))/gi);

function checker() {
    str = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
    //str = str.innerText;
    for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
       str[i].id = String(i+"para");
        console.log(str[i].innerText);
        inner = str[i].innerText;
        //Now make an if statement to if we go further
        //res = isCurrency(inner); //This passes correctly
        res = 1;
        if(res === 1){
            if(regAUD.test(inner)){
                inner = inner.replace(regAUD, '<b>$1</b>');
                console.log(inner);
                console.log("Done?");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I assume I am using the function incorrectly. It does show up in the console but not in the elements expected. It doesn't change anything, ie I expect it to currently make 10AUD and 500AUD bold but it does not do this. Is there a better method to achieve this change in the DOM or have I used this function incorrectly?

Comment: The variable `inner` is a *copy* of the `innerText` of the element. You have to explicitly change `innerHTML` (because that's what you want to replace it with) in order for the DOM to be updated.

Comment: Also all your variables should be declared with `let` or `var`.

Comment: Oh also you don't need the explicit `RegExp` constructor; just the `/.../` regex literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to affect your new HTML string to the concerned elements' own HTML.

Also, you could have a shorter function.

Here's one with two parameters:

- `selector` to execute the highlight on wanted elements.
- `currency` to highlight the wanted currency.

```js
// Highlights "AUD" mentions winthin all <p> elements.
highlightCurrencyFromElement('p', 'aud');

function highlightCurrencyFromElement(selector, currency) {
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector),
    pattern = new RegExp(`(\\d+\\s*${currency})`, 'gi');
    
  for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].innerHTML = elements[i].innerHTML.replace(pattern, '<b>$1</b>');
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>5</p>
  <p>21 AUD</p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>50AUD</p>
  <p>50 €</p>
  <p>87 USD</p>
  <span>20 AUD (in span, so no highlighted)</span>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the paragraph innerHTML porperty after replacing regxmatch to replace in DOM.

```
regAUD = RegExp(/([0-9]+(AUD))/gi);

function checker() {
    str = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
    //str = str.innerText;
    for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
       str[i].id = String(i+"para");
        console.log(str[i].innerText);
        inner = str[i].innerText;
        //Now make an if statement to if we go further
        //res = isCurrency(inner); //This passes correctly
        res = 1;
        if(res === 1){
            if(regAUD.test(inner)){
                inner = inner.replace(regAUD, '<b>$1</b>');
                str[i].innerHTML= inner;
                console.log(inner);
                console.log("Done?");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the `innerText` is updated, the `<b>` will be rendered literally and not interpreted as HTML markup.

Comment: Try using innerHTML in place of innerText. That was a typo mistake. sorry for the inconvenience and Thanks for highlighting the same.